# Bad Late Answer Audits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, disputed-review-audits, late-answers

There are numerous posts on meta, including [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) that discuss when answers should be flagged, and the general consensus, particularly among moderators, is that if a post attempts to answer the question, it should not be flagged just because its incorrect.

A week or so ago, I was in the LA queue, and after making a review, the next one took an abnormally long time to load, which often indicates that its an audit. The answer appeared to answer the question, but I decided to take a look, and the answer had been flagged with the *"This does not provide an answer ... - From Review"* comment and had been deleted (even though it should never have entered the review queue). I took some appropriate action (can't remember but I assume I gave it a down vote) and smirked at the congratulatory message.

2 days ago I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/15644026) because I clicked *No Action Needed*. The answer may be wrong, and correctly down voted, but its an attempt to answer (it suggests OP's code of `<context:component-scan base-package="cm.*" />` be replaced with `<context:component-scan base-package="cm.*,cm.tasks.jobs" />`) and it should not have entered the LQP queue.

To be clear, I am not concerned about the failed audit - I have made 35K+ reviews and as far as I recall, have only failed a handful of audits.

Because of the fail, I decided to take a look at each question/answer when reviewing the LA queue yesterday, and sure enough, came across another audit with a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847487/copy-git-folder-terminal-with-copy-all), (screenshot below) which is an attempt to answer the question. It may not be great, and it may be wrong, but again, it should not have entered the LQP queue (and therefore not have been deleted via the queue).

[image]

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the LA review process, and that I should only click *No Action Needed* if I am absolutely certain the answer is correct, then it means there have been at least 3 dubious audits candidates in the last 2 weeks.

Short of posting such examples here (and let a moderator decide if they should be removed as audits), is there anything I can do to flag these as possible suspect audits?

Or should the algorithm for determining audits be changed to exclude answers that have been deleted in other review queues (unless perhaps a moderator was involved in nuking it)?

Comment: You can flag the post for moderator *"Incorrectly deleted in LQP review queue"*, they can undelete it and this way it will most probably not be an audit anymore (they can also have a look at the reviewers), anyway your suggestion of having only mod nuked stuff as audit's is interesting but will probably be 6-8 of random time unit.

Comment: I think we need some hard data about how many audits have been failed for posts that were deleted based on enough flags from the review queue as this seems to generate more false positives then posts that were deleted by moderator and are used for a review. There are two possible actions: don't nominate posts that were deleted under the new rules for audits; educate reviewers about taking the correct action or skip. The latter might be hard as it will not be easy for regular users to find these posts.

Comment: I also noticed that it had [2 Looks OK](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15552639) in review queue, so yeah at least do not push post with Looks OK as audits.

Comment: It is an answer, obviously, maybe a bad one, but still, stating that it is not an answer is not correct.

Comment: this is another one http://stackoverflow.com/a/43092985/5292302

Comment: @rene if anecdote is any reference: the spam and plagiarization audits seems to be the causes of most audits failures,

Comment: "and it should not have entered the LQP queue." it wasn't because it was flagged, it was because it's quality is so bad that the system shoves it to the LQRQ so someone can take a stab to improve it (which is one of the reasons of the queue, no?). Don't blame flaggers for these!

Comment: @PetterFriberg I disagree with the moderator deletion audits because many times a moderator has to do a lot of digging to be able to determine whether a post should be deleted or not, and reviewers should not be expected to do that kind of digging. I think that actual past review tasks are the only way to go that makes any sense, but it should only be for unanimous consensus outcomes, and should exclude any known-good posts from being audits if they have received downvotes or close votes, and known-bad posts from being audits if they have received any upvotes. The last part should be in effect

Comment: @PetterFriberg has the answer: the audit should use examples that were unanimous because that should weed out people who aren't thinking about it.

Comment: @Braiam that is true but this case isn't that, right? Or would you have flagged that answer as rude?

Comment: @rene spam flags validated by self deletion are one PITA, normally.

Comment: *took an abnormally long time to load, which often indicates that its an audit* Aww now you have gone and removed the mystery ;-) (Funny I never made that connection)